Find the missing animal
What is the missing animal in this list:

dog
ostrich
snake
monkey
bull
cow
peacock

Hint:

 It's gambling


I think the missing animal is

 Ram

The animals listed are

 included in the Brazilian gambling game called Jogo do bicho

There are

 a total of 25 different animals listed from 1-25 in a 5x5 grid. And OP's method seems to be to cross the two diagonals but excluding the central animal which is a rooster, leaving us with the ram being the only animal not presented in the list of the puzzle 


This looks like good logic to me and fits with the hint +1

Interesting how the double zero is at the end, instead of at the beginning... clearly not created by a programmer :)
